# How do RSA fingerprints protect from MITM attacks?

Tags: cryptography, authentication, ssh, man-in-the-middle

I understand that RSA fingerprints are used to verify that you are really connecting directly to who you want to connect to, and not someone else posing as that site.

Like when you do a `git push`, it shows you an RSA key, then you can go to a webpage and see if the key you got matches the key on their webpage.

But what's to stop someone else from finding out the public RSA key that the site is using, and then replying with that same key, in order to pretend to be that site?

Answer (score 11):

Some good information in the other answers as well, but to answer your question directly:

> But what's to stop someone else from finding out the public RSA key that the site is using, and then replying with that same key, in order to pretend to be that site?

An attacker could do this, and they could trick you into encrypting your data using the public key and sending it to them. However, without the corresponding private key, this information would be useless to them because they would be unable to decrypt it.

Comment: public key (lets say this key is owned by A's side) is just used by someone (B side)  to encrypt data. You cannot do anything else with this key. Only A can decrypt the data with its' private key. However if you know what you are encrypting with the key you can match data like this but it means you are the server or you know 100% how the server respond to a request

Answer (score 9):

Public keys are exactly that - public, intended for distribution. Having a copy of a public key doesn't allow you, on its own, to masquerade as the key's owner. It gives you the ability to encrypt data that you send to the owner in a manner that only the owner can decrypt it, using the private key that corresponds with the public key. It also allows you to decrypt data that was encrypted using the private key, proving that the data came from the owner of the private key, which is the use here - your copy of the public key allows you to be reasonably certain that the server you are communicating with is trustworthy (to the extent that you can trust the owner of the private key to maintain the secrecy of that private key).

Provided the owner keeps the private key, private, the system works as intended.

The Wikipedia article on [public-key cryptography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) gives a good introduction to how things like RSA, DSA etc work.

Answer (score 2):

The fingerprint is computed from the associated public key and can be calculated by your computer. If the fingerprint matches what you expect, then the key you are encrypting to is the appropriate one for your target.

While one can report a false fingerprint, the fact that they can be independently calculated from the actual possessed key makes pretty much useless unless the hash used for fingerprinting is small enough that a collision is realistically possible. Without a collision, any exchange of data would still be encrypted to the appropriate public key (since you verified that the one you're using matches the expected hash) and could not be decrypted without the corresponding private key.

Answer (score 2):

## The short

The MITM needs the private key of the server to pose as the server and decrypt
private messages you send to to the server. The public key of the server is for
authenticating messages signed by the server and sending private messages to
the server, so you still need to verify its fingerprint. It's okay if the MITM
has the public key too. All that means is that the MITM can also authenticate messages from the
server and send private messages to the server.

In general, if all public keys are known to everyone, anyone can authenticate
anyone's signatures and anyone can send a private message to anyone. The private
key controls signing and decryption, so ideally no one can pose as another, and
no one can read a private message sent to another.

## The long

*NB: The following is simplified model for educational purposes only, intended to
illustrate the point of the public key fingerprint. See [this other question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/76894/how-does-ssh-use-both-rsa-and-diffie-hellman) for more SSH details.*

**Review.** For simplicity, instead of SSH over a computer network, consider a
public cork-board where agents can post text notes. At the start, the board is
blank. Agents `A` and `S` want to communicate, and wish to protect the privacy
and integrity of their messages from malicious agent `M`. Assume private keys
are known only to their respective owners.

1. `A` posts `A_pub`, and `S` posts `S_pub`.
2. `A` encrypts a message with `S_pub`, signs with `A_priv`, and posts.
3. `S` decrypts the message with `S_priv`, verifies signature using `A_pub`.
4. `S` encrypts a response with `A_pub`, signs with `S_priv`, and posts.
5. I think you know what `A` does here.

Agent `M` cannot decrypt these messages. `M` *can* post encrypted messages
to `S` or `A`. However, an attempt at forgery would fail. A message signed with
`M_priv` would not pass verification using `A_pub` or `S_pub`.

**Now for the function of the public key fingerprint.** Suppose `M` creates
`M_pub` and `M_priv`, and attempts to fool `A` by posting `M_pub` as `S_pub`:

```
Dear A,

My public key is

   [contents of M_pub]

Love,
S
```

If
`A` believes this lie, `A` will encrypt messages to `S` with `M_pub` so that `M`
can decrypt them, and `M` can forge messages as `S` using `M_priv`. However, if
`A` has the fingerprint of `S_pub`, `A` can compare it with the fingerprint of
`M_pub` and discover the lie. Hence `A` will refuse to use `M_pub` for
encryption of messages to `S` and authentication of messages from `S`.

Therefore when SSH gives a warning about the pubic key fingerprint being unknown
or changed, it means you could be the victim of an MITM attack. If you proceed,
the MITM will be able to decrypt your messages and forge responses as the
server. If the fingerprint check succeeds you have a very high confidence you
are not a victim of MITM, assuming the fingerprint you have is the real
fingerprint of the server, the private keys (both yours and the server's) are
indeed private, the implementations of SSH are correct, and the public-key crypto math is not
compromised.

Comment: No, the server does not need the private ssh key.  The server in an SSH connection only needs the public key.  None of my servers have ever had the private  key.

Comment: @rippledj The server needs a private host key.

Comment: @rippledj: you might be confused by the fact SSH uses **different keypairs** for server and client. The server authenticates to the client using the server keypair (called hostkey) and the client authenticates to the server using the client keypair. If you are the client, the server has only your public key, but it has its own private _and_ public key, and you have _its_ public key in your known_hosts file. (Actually most servers have several keypairs, one for each type supported -- RSA, DSA, ECDSA-n, Ed25519 -- because it can't predict which types different clients will support and permit.)

Comment: Ok got it.  But are these authentication keys used for layer encryption, or only for authentication?

Comment: @rippledj Just authentication, session keys are generated before authentication happens, usually with diffie-hellman.

Comment: Which means that a MITM can forge separate session keys to both client and server, holding ALL clear text data in between.  A sophisticated MITM can keep the connection alive after the client attempts to terminate the connection, or even inject commands while client is connected and filter out packets that reveal the MITM.  So, RSA fingerprints are useless to use as evidence of a secure connection.  Only a VPN, with preshared enc-layer keys, can mitigate this.  However, merely attempting to share those keys to setup your vpn, they can be picked off by pervasive MITM.

Comment: For this reason, I am currently writing a scipt that is used after the VPS server is initiated and a first VPN is created.  The scipt will come with a separately encrypted payload and once on the VPS will roll over all the VPN keys.  This is required in lieu of not having physical access to the VPS.  Otherwise a compromised home router or the NSA working with the ISP can pwn your VPS at will.

Comment: Here is a link to OpenVPN manual for static (pre-shared) key encryption. https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/manuals/openvpn-20x-manpage.html#lbBA.

Answer (score 2):

SSH host authentication occurs during the [key exchange](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4253#section-7). The key exchange is generally done using [Diffie-Hellman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange), which allows generating a shared secret that can be used as a symmetric session key.

#### Making sure the host has the private key

At the start of the key exchange, a signing algorithm is negotiated (this can be RSA, DSA, etc). At the end of the [key exchange](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4253#section-8), the host uses this signing algorithm with its private key to [sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature) the previously exchanged data. The host sends its public key and the signature to the client (along with the Diffie-Hellman stuff), and the client uses the host's public key to verify the signature. Since a signature can only be created with the private key, the client knows that the host has access to the private key corresponding to the public key the host presented.

#### Making sure it's the correct host

The client has a few ways of verifying that it's talking to the correct host. If it has previously connected to the host, it can match the host's public key against a local database to make sure the host presented the same public key that it did previously.

During the key exchange, the host can also opt to send a certificate signed by a [CA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority) that the client trusts instead of sending just the public key; the client can then verify that the host's public key was signed by the CA (although in practice certificates aren't used with ssh very often).

If the host key can't be automatically verified, a fingerprint (hash of the host's public key) is often presented to the user to allow them to manually verify it **out-of-band**. If accepted by the user, the public key will then generally be stored to allow automatic verification for future connections.

---

**So to answer your question:** Any host could copy any other host's public key, but it would be unable to produce a valid signature for the key exchange, and the client would abort with an error. As long as you verify the host key's fingerprint **out-of-band** (like you are by checking the website, over HTTPS I hope), MitM is prevented.

Answer (score 0):

It does not only show you the RSA key. It also encrypts the communication using a public / private key pair (including that RSA key). This way you are sure only server X can be the server ( since normally only server X has the private key).

You can read more about public / private keys [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28algorithm%29) . There is quite some math involved.

Comment: git over (current) SSH uses only RSA signature, not encryption, although the server's privatekey being only on the server remains true.

Answer (score -2):

If I am not mistaken, the function that is used to generate the fingerprint uses the private key to do so.  So the fingerprint cannot* be recreated without the private key.

*There's the possibility of collisions since the range of values that valid fingerprints are less than the range of values of valid keys.  It's sufficiently rare to still enable fingerprints to be useful.

Comment: Actually, I believe the fingerprint is (roughly) a hash of the public key and can be generated without the private key

Comment: it would still need the private key to make the communication happen since the client will use the public key.

Comment: If the fingerprint was a hash of the private key, you would need to private key to verify it!

Comment: The _communication_ (specifically, the handshake authentication=signature) does require the privatekey, but the _fingerprint_ does not; it is indeed a hash of the publickey, more specifically of the publickey encoding included in the host's final 'KEX' (keyexchange) message.